# JMETER + POST + anti-forgery token

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

When I try to run performance testing on ASP.net web application, always i am getting either "The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match." 
or 
"The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the  configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster."

Could you please help me how to resolve this. I have tried multiple methods like adding regular expression extractor to extract  "__RequestVerificationToken", but nothing worked out.

Note: this is happening only when i run from Jmeter. if I browse application directly on web, i dont see any issue.

Thanks,
Pani

Comment: can you show how you handled the token ? I mean the extraction and how you inject it? thanks

Answer (score 9):

Looking into [XSRF/CSRF Prevention in ASP.NET MVC and Web Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages) it appears that you're either sending an incorrect `__RequestVerificationToken` parameter value or completely miss the step.

> If the current HTTP request already contains an anti-XSRF session token (the anti-XSRF cookie __RequestVerificationToken), the security token is extracted from it. If the HTTP request does not contain an anti-XSRF session token or if extraction of the security token fails, a new random anti-XSRF token will be generated.

So your test should look like:

- Open Login Page (HTTP Get Request)

  - Extract `__RequestVerificationToken` dynamic parameter value using suitable [JMeter PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), I would recommend going for [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor), the configuration would be something like:

    [image]
- Once done you can refer the extracted value as `${token}` in the next request

  [image]

Check out [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) article for more detailed information and step-by-step instructions if needed

Comment: Just a heads up that, depending on how your application is set up, you could have multiple tokens on one page, so make sure your regular expression is setup correctly.

Comment: Ok, in my case when the homepage is load, three forms are there login, signup and forgot password and all this having different RequestVerificationToken. I extract token and stored in variable but not sure which one is used for login form and how to extract each one?

Comment: The one which is in login form should be used for logging in, no?

Comment: yes, that one should use but how can we extract it from loginForm? that is my question.